# why is this code giving me "expected unqualified-id" error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

here is the ideone link:
https://ideone.com/0fqnCG

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string cases[8] = {"TTT", "TTH", "THT", "THH", "HTT", "HTH", "HHT", "HHH"};
    int p, j, i;
    cin >> p;
    int sets[p];
    string toss[p];
    string new;
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        cin >> sets[i];
        cin >> toss[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < p; ++i)
    {
        int case1 = 0, case2 = 0, case3 = 0, case4 = 0, case5 = 0, case6 = 0, case7 = 0, case8 = 0;
        new = toss[i];
        cout << sets[i];
        for (j = 0; j < 38; ++j)
        {
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[0]) {case1++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[1]) {case2++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[2]) {case3++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[3]) {case4++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[4]) {case5++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[5]) {case6++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[6]) {case7++;}
            if (new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[7]) {case8++;}
        }
        cout << case1 << " " << case2 << " " << case3 << " " << case4 << " " << case5 << " " << case6 << " " << case7 << " " << case8 << " ";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE:this is the solution to a problem on uva,here is the link to the problem:https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2874

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using keyword as variable**

There are various errors in your program: 
 `new` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use it for naming variables. The reason is that it will be treated as not a variable, but the keyword with all its functionalities. Try `new1` instead (or any name other than a reserved keyword).

**String and char comparisons, concatenation:**

`(new[i] + new[i + 1] + new[i + 2] == cases[0])`

Here `new[i]`, (change it to (`new1[i]`) is a character, and `cases[0]` is a string. Also, adding characters in this way will not *concatenate* them, but will generate another character based on the addition of their ascii values. 
Instead, try this:

```
if ((new[i] == cases[0][0] && (new[i+1] == cases[0][1]) && (new[i+2] == cases[0][2])) 
{case1++;}
```

[Here is the modified code](http://ideone.com/Ux7R28)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a c++ compiler (and clearly you are!), new is a reserved word and can't be used as a variable identifier.